# Bootstrap Datepicker not allowing dd-mm-yyy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
<input class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Date field is required." id="Date" name="Date" type="text">
```

i have specified data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" as guided here.
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker#example

The problem is it is not allowing dd/mm/yyyy format to pass through.
I am using asp.net mvc if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

In your model, do you have the following dataannotation set for your field:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText="", DataFormatString = " {0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime myDate { get; set; }
```

You should also have in your web.config under system.web:

```
<globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" />
```

If you want to do client side validation, you should also include https://github.com/jquery/globalize

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/scripts/globalize.culture.en-AU.js"></script>
```

Finally, I create an EditorTemplate for Date fields:

```
/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/date.cshtml:

@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToShortDateString(), new { @class = "datepicker"})
```

Comment: yes i do... beside this.. DataType(DataType.Date) it adds input type date.. which i do not need. as it adds browsers default datepicker